# How to use the progress indicator in "open from cloud"?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, monitoring

I like the circular loading indicator seen in the "save to the cloud" dialog:

[image]

Is there any way to call it programmatically?

Comment: `ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace"]` comes close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is something along those lines:

```
Framed[
  DynamicModule[{t = 0}
  , Overlay[
      {
        Animator[Dynamic@t, AppearanceElements -> None, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity
        , AnimationRate -> 1
        ]
      , Rotate[ Dynamic @ RawBoxes @ FEPrivate`ImportImage[
          FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "CloudDialogs"}, "ProgressSpinner.png"]
        ], Dynamic[2 Pi t]]
      }
    , ImageSize -> {100, 100}, Alignment -> Center]
  ]
, Background -> Gray
]
```

[image]